# Addins tab missing in Outlook 2007 ribbon

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007, outlook-addin

I can see Addins tab is missing from Outlook 2007 ribbon on some PCs. In most cases it's there. But in some cases Addins tab is hidden so all addins buttons are not available. Is there a way to display it?

Answer (score 1):

The "AddIns" tab in Office 2007 is only visible if the addin is using old features such as the CommandBars, MenuItems etc in version 2007.

For e.g. if an old COM addin createa a new commandbar with 2 buttons and adds a new menu "MyMenu" then these will be displayed in the "AddIns" tab in Office 2007. AddIns are now suppose to use the Ribbon feature.

Also, if the addin changes/repurposes some commands using the CommandBar object the repurposed commands, menu items will be added to "AddIns" tab.

Comment: That's right. I install my addin and my command buttons are displayed in the Addins tab. But on some PCs I can't see the Addins tab. It seems to be disabled.

Comment: Does your addin adds the commands to the CommandBars based on some condition? It might be possible that the addin's CommandBar initialization code is failing on some machine because of which it is not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

use office button (most top left button) -> word button (or excel or ...) -> Add-Ins

Comment: There's no Office button in Outlook. But anyway the addin is installed correctly and listed in the addins list you're talking about.